# Why are my if functions not preventing the segue to the next view controller?

Tags: swift, if-statement, segue

I have a series of if functions that check if two text fields are empty (or just one of them) and if so, present an error message in a label. If both of the text fields are not empty, then it should execute a calculation and then segue to the following view controller and present the value from the equation in a label. However, even with if functions in place that check to see if the text fields are not nil, the segue still gets executed, even if they are nil, as do the error labels. Why are the if functions not preventing this?

```
@IBAction func CalcFlowRateEnd(_ sender: UIButton) {
  
    let volume = Double(VolTextField.text!)
    let time = Double(SecTextField.text!)
    let units = volumeUnitsPicker4.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    var selectedUnit = data[units]

        
        //milliliters error labels
    if selectedUnit == "milliliters" && volume == nil && time == nil {
            volErrorLabel.text = "Enter Volume"
            secErrorLabel.text = "Enter Seconds"}
        
    if selectedUnit == "milliliters" && volume != nil && time == nil {
            secErrorLabel.text = "Enter Seconds"}
        
    if selectedUnit == "milliliters" && volume == nil && time != nil {
            volErrorLabel.text = "Enter Volume"}
        
        
        //milliliters calc
    if selectedUnit == "milliliters" && volume != nil && time != nil{
    
    let volumeConvert = Double(volume!/1000)
    let timeConvert = Double(time! / 60)
    let flowRateMetric = Double(volumeConvert / timeConvert)
    let volumeImperial = Double(volume!/4546)
    let flowRateImperial = Double(volumeImperial / timeConvert)
    let roundedMetric = round(flowRateMetric * 100) / 100.0
    let roundedImperial = round(flowRateImperial * 100) / 100.0
            
    calcFlowRate.text = "\(roundedMetric) liters per min or \(roundedImperial) gal per min"
        
    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                 
    let flowRate = calcFlowRate.text ?? ""
    let destinationVC = segue.destination as! FlowRateCalcEndViewController
    destinationVC.flowRate = flowRate
            
    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that has anything to do with performing segues. Please post a minimal but complete example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Agree with @Rudedog - there is no line of code with regards to performing a segue. I feel you might have wired this up in your storyboard or you are missing a few lines of code

Comment: Yes, I created the segue in the storyboard. It goes from the button in the code above to the following view controller. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prepare(for segue)` function should not be nested within your `@IBAction` function.

`func prepare(for segue)` should be overwritten. It's called before the segue is performed so you have a chance to "do something"

```
var isFlowRateCalculated = false

@IBAction func CalcFlowRateEnd(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if selectedUnit == "milliliters" && volume != nil && time != nil {
    // logic

    isFlowRateCalculated = true
   }
}

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return isFlowRateCalculated
}

override func prepare(for segue) {
    // hand off data for view being presented
}
```

This doesn't solve your entire problem but it's a step in the right direction. Happy to continue talking about this with you :)

I also recommend taking a look at this article on [Medium](https://medium.com/a-developer-in-making/how-to-pass-data-using-segue-and-unwind-in-swift-afaf241186fc)

Comment: thank you very much, that's so kind and helpful of you. So far, i can manage to get the information to post on the second view controller since I did as you said and took the override func prepare(for segue) out of the button. However, even if I put an if function that checks if the textfields are nil, it still segues to the next view controller. I tried removing the segue and adding code to go to the next view controller. I can then get to the next view controller but the information doesn't make it. I can't seem to figure out how to have both.

Comment: There's another method you can override. `func shouldPerformSegue`. [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621502-shouldperformsegue) Your `IBAction` can be your primary logic, then `override func shouldPerformSegue` will be called. That's where you could include some of your **if statement** logic to determine whether or not the segue should be performed.

Comment: I updated the original answer with a rough outline of what you could try next :)

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, this worked! I wasn't aware of shouldPerformSegue.

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked out for you :) Good luck with the rest of your work!